# Product of compact sets is compact proof

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove that the product of two compact sets is also compact. Here is what I have.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact. Let $\{G_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be an open cover for $X\mathopen\times Y$. Then $$X\mathopen\times Y\subset\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}G_{\lambda}.$$ We know that the compactness of $Y$ implies the compactness of $\{x\}\mathopen\times Y$ for any fixed $x\in X$. Therefore we have a finite subcover for $\{x\}\mathopen\times Y$ giving, $$\{x\}\mathopen\times Y\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^{n\mathopen{}\left(x\right)}G_{\lambda_{i\mathopen{}\left(x\right)}}^x,$$ for some suitable choice of $\lambda_{1\mathopen{}\left(x\right)},\dots,\lambda_{n\mathopen{}\left(x\right)}$. Since $$X\mathopen\times Y=\bigcup_{x\in X}\{x\}\mathopen\times Y\subset\bigcup_{x\in X}\bigcup_{i=1}^{n\mathopen{}\left(x\right)}G_{\lambda_{i\mathopen{}\left(x\right)}}^x$$ and $X$ is compact, $$X\mathopen\times Y\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^m\bigcup_{i=1}^{n\mathopen{}\left(x_j\right)}G_{\lambda_{i\mathopen{}\left(x_j\right)}}^{x_j},$$ for some $x_1,\dots,x_m$. This is a finite subcover (?).

Is this proof correct? The part I am most uncertain about is the last step. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, the proof is not quite correct. At the very least, you need to explain what you meant by $X\subset \cup_{j=1}^{m}\cup_{i=1}^{n(x_j)}G_{\lambda_{i(x_j)}}^{x_j}$, since the sets on the right are subsets of $X\times Y$ whereas $X$ (in general) is not.

Comment: Oops, you are right. That was a typo on my part and $X$ should be $X\mathopen\times Y$.

Comment: Still, the assertion that there exist $x_1,\ldots x_m$ as in your description doesn't follow immediately from compactness and needs further justification.